# Virtual-machine loses save state after reboot

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, images, virtual-machine, reboot

Every time I restart/shut down my VM in VirtualBox (image is Ubuntu 10.02), whenever I start it back up, it reverts to the state it was in after I installed Guest Additions. This is extremely frustrating as every time I make progress on a project, whenever it restarts (mostly from crashing), I have to redo mostly everything. Is this a known problem with Guest Additions or with Virtual Box in general, and if so is there some solution?

Comment: Are you restoring from Snapshot when you boot up the VM ?

Comment: Maybe mentioning the version of VirtualBox you use might help.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the "Restore current snapshot" check box in the "Close Virtual Machine" dialog is unchecked.  If it is checked, VirtualBox will revert to the current snapshot, losing any changes since the last snapshot.